# Misunderstanding on the use of Popoviciu and von Szokefalvi Nagy's inequalities on the variance of a unbiased estimator

Tags: variance, random-variable, unbiased-estimator, iid, inequality

Let $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ be (discrete in my case) i.i.d. and bounded between $m$ and $M$. I'm interested in bounding the variance of an unbiased estimator:
$$\mathbb{V}\left[\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right]$$
On the one hand, we have:
$$\mathbb{V}\left[\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right]=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$$
where $\sigma^2$ is the variance of $X_1$. Using Popoviciu's inequality, this gives me
$\sigma^2\leqslant\frac14\left(M-m\right)^2$, which I can then inject into the previous formulae:
$$\mathbb{V}\left[\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right]\leqslant\frac{\left(M-m\right)^2}{4n}$$
But on the other hand, from my understanding, von Szokefalvi Nagy's inequality gives:
$$\frac{\left(M-m\right)^2}{2n}\leqslant\mathbb{V}\left[\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right]$$
Clearly, these two results are inconsistent. Where is the error in this reasoning? Which of the two formulaes is wrong?

Comment: I think if you consider $n=1$ you will quickly find counterexamples to your final expression: how could the variance of $X_1$ possibly have any lower bound greater than zero??

Comment: @whuber You're right, I didn't look for counterexamples! Setting $X_i$ to be a constant random variable makes no sense in the last expression. But in that case, in which context should this lower-bound be used? Or does the last inequality assume $m$ and $M$ to be tight? That is, we assume that $X_i$ did reach both of them at least once?

Comment: Since the lower bound obviously is incorrect, your question "which of the two formulas is wrong" has been settled.